# where to defining environmental variable in helm-charts?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have 2 pods in the aks and first pod is consuming services from second pod. to establish the connection, i need to set env variable. I want to know where to define those env variable in helm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `deployment.yaml`
at the path
`spec.template.spec.containers`

It goes something like this

```
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
      imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
      env:         
        - name: JPDA_ADDRESS
          value: '*:8000'
...
```

So, once you run the above, if you do
`kubectl exec my-pod -c my-container -- "echo $JPDA_ADDRESS"`, it will print `*:8000`

It is important to understand, that Helm simply manages templates for Kubernetes objects. Helm's `deployment.yaml` produces a YAML spec for Kube object of `kind: Deployment`. So, if you want to know every possible field you can specify in deployment.yaml, you can run `kubectl explain deployment --recursive` anywhere you have `kubectl` running.

Comment: Will this method application when my pods are running in azure dev spaces and not in default namespace

Comment: @sushantkumar while I personally have no experience with Azure, the whole purpose of Kubernetes / Helm is to behave the same everywhere, otherwise it has failed its mission. This method definitely works in Google's GCP and in AWS and in barebone Kube and in docker-for-desktop on developer's machines. I am sure Azure will follow suit.

Comment: Also, pleas don't forget to upvote if it works for you (when it does, and if you find it helpful, no rush).